# How to setup an array in PHP with a variable inserted

Tags: php

I am an ASP programmer trying to write PHP, so my apologies if this is really basic. I have a variable $fname and I am trying to setup an array as follows:

```
$data=array('x_First_Name' => '" . str_replace("'" ,"\'", $fname) . "');
```

But, I get an error:
unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ')'

Something simple in my syntax that needs to be adjusted?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to quote the value:

```
$data=array('x_First_Name' => str_replace("'" ,"\'", $fname) );
```

You might also find PHP's [`addslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) helpful:

```
$data=array('x_First_Name' => addslashes($fname));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have only a variable or a function, you don't need to add quotes. And to 'break' the quotes for a function or a variable, you need to use the same quotes.

`$data=array('x_First_Name' => str_replace("'" ,"\'", $fname));`